# JTextArea wrap line with CR LF

Tags: java, jtextarea

I want to read a file and wrap its lines into a `JTextArea` when the reading encounter a CR LF value.

`JTextArea` has methods like `setLineWrap` and `setWrapStyleWord` that doesn't do that!

Thanks.

Comment: This is the default behaviour. Whenever a newline string is found the text wraps to the next line. So your question doesn't make any sense. Post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace CRLF with \n

The Linewrapping methods you mentioned are something slightly different - they wrap lines that are too long to fit into the JTextArea.

Comment: Under Windows \n is equals to CRLF while under Linux is equal to LF and so my file already contain it!

Comment: Don't replace in your file.. replace in the string which you want to be shown inside your JTextArea.

Comment: Ok it works, thanks ... but it wasn't better that a JTextArea was able to process CRLF to put a new line? LF is not equivalent to \n ASCII code 0xA? may be in Linux could work? I must try it!

Comment: @xdevel2000, A JText area does suppot \r\n as a new line string. There is no need to convert it.

Answer (score 0):

\r (CR) wont line feed (LF) . 
\n (LF) will line feed. 
\r\n (CRLF) will line feed.

so odd that jTextArea doesn't provide a configuration option for that.